# Cross Project Data access and Slot Utilization in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Project A and Project B both with flat rate pricing models.
Project A has all the data that Users from Project B want to access.
We have assigned Users from Project B data viewer role on Project A.
How can we ensure (other than selecting Project B from the Dropdown menu on the top) that Users from Project B will always use Slots from Project B's Slot pool whilst accessing data from Project A?

Comment: Without a **BigQuery Job User**  role on Project A,  users from Project B  can't run a query job on Project A.    https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery

Comment: Thanks for replying can Users have access to Project A's data without granting them the BigQuery Job User role?

Comment: yes. it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario below, Project B's slots will be used as it is where the jobs are created:

1. Project A: owns data and the datasets.
2. Project B: users from this project run query jobs.

So in the case that you want to ensure that the users from project B will use project B slots you have to create the job in project B but having access to the project A.

You could also use [authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) to share specific query results to particular users or groups without giving them access to the underlying tables, or the whole dataset.

For the comment that you say to access data without the BigQuery Job User?
The answer is yes you can access the data.

What you can add is the permission `bigquery.jobs.create` instead of adding the role BigQuery Job User that has that permission between others. You can check in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/jobs-overview#required_permissions) what are the permissions required or if you want to set a role in order to create a BigQuery job.